# How to remove mipmap directory, colors.xml, and styles.xml files programmatically?

Tags: android, plugins

I'm developing an Android studio plugin for my company. We need to develop a plugin using minimal resources. So, I wanted to remove layout file, colors.xml, styles.xml files, drawable and mipmap folders programmatically.

I am able to not generate layouts files from receipe.xml.ftl. However, I can not able to stop generating other .xml files which are automatically generated by an Android Studio at the time of new project creation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In receipe.xml.ftl file, I removed,                                                            <#if generateLayout>
    <#include "../common/recipe_simple.xml.ftl" />
    <open file="${escapeXmlAttribute(resOut)}/layout/${layoutName}.xml" />, </#if>   hence, Android Studio will not generate any layout files.

Comment: Use your post to post a question. Not comments. Act normal please.

Comment: How can I remove these resources??